# Generating and solving recurrence relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to do this question but don't know where to go from here:
The question:
For $n\ge1$ let $t_n$ be the number of ways to tile the squares of a 2xn checkerboard using 1x2(which can be rotated to be 2x1 tiles) and 2x2 tiles, if the 1x2 tiles come in 5 different colors and the 2x2 tiles in 4 different colors. Find and solve a recurrence relation for $t_n$.

I think I first part of 1x2 tiles to be :
$t_n=3t_{n-1} +9t_{n-2}$

Is that part right? and how do i go from here

Comment: To tile or to color? In other words, for $2\times 2,$ do you distinguished between covering by red  $2\times 1$ tiles and red $1\times 2$ tiles? The coloring question is harder.

Comment: just to tile, so there is no difference between 2x1 and 1x2 tile.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can clearly see that $T_0 = 1, T_1 = 5, T_2 = 54$, so your relation is wrong.

**Hint:** The recurrance relation is $T_n = 5 T_{n-1} + 29 T_{n-2}$. Why?